# Image of integer coefficient polynomial on unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let T be an unit circle and f(x) be an integer coefficient polynomial.

> Then What is $f(T)$?

Using complex analysis,
I think there is a point z in T such that |f(z)|>=1. But I do not know why this happend.

Comment: What is your question? do you want to show there is a $z$ on $T$ such that $|f(z)| \ge 1$ or you already know how to prove that but you want some insight why that's is true.

Comment: I want to know how to prove.

Comment: Factor $f(z)$ as $g(z)z^m$ where $g(0) \ne 0$ and $m$ is the multiplicity if $0$ is a root of $f(z)$. Now what does maximum modulus principle tell us?

Comment: Using Cauchy's estimate. right? then nonzero constant term is smaller than f(z) for some z in T

Comment: I have another quetion. We know that there is a point such that modulus of its image is larger than 1. Then what is a real part of this point? I hope that it is positive value.

Comment: It need not be positive, the simplest counterexample is $x-2$. The real part is negative for all $x \in T$.

Answer (score 1):

Unless $f(z)\equiv0$, since $\max\limits_{|z|=1}\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^n}\right|=\max\limits_{|z|=1}\left|\,f(z)\,\right|$, we can assume $f(0)\ne0$. Since $f(0)\in\mathbb{Z}$, we must have $\left|\,f(0)\,\right|\ge1$.

Polynomials are holomorphic, so they have the [Mean Value Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property):
$$
f(0)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f\!\left(e^{it}\right)\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}
$$

Suppose
$$
\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left|\,f\!\left(e^{it}\right)-f(0)\,\right|^2\,\mathrm{d}t=\sigma^2\tag{2}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left|\,f\!\left(e^{it}\right)\,\right|^2\,\mathrm{d}t
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(2\mathrm{Re}\!\left(\,f\!\left(e^{it}\right)\overline{f(0)}\right)-\left|\,f(0)\,\right|^2\right)\,\mathrm{d}t+\sigma^2\\[6pt]
&=\left|\,f(0)\,\right|^2+\sigma^2\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, if $\left|\,f(0)\,\right|\gt1$ or $\sigma^2\gt0$, then $(3)$ says that for some $t\in[0,2\pi]$, we have $\left|\,f\!\left(e^{it}\right)\,\right|\gt1$.

If $\left|\,f(0)\,\right|=1$ and $\sigma^2=0$, then $f(z)=f(0)=\pm1$ for all $z$.

> Therefore, except for $f(z)=\pm z^n$ and $f(z)=0$, all polynomials with integer coefficients satisfy
>   $$
> \max_{|z|=1}\left|\,f(z)\,\right|\gt1\tag{4}
> $$

Comment: Thank you!!! We know that there is a point a in |z|=1 such that |f(a)|=max|f(z)|.  Then what is probability that Re(a)>=0??

Comment: If $g(x)=f(-x)$, then$$\left|f(a)\right| =\max\limits_{\left|x\right|=1}\left|f(x)\right| \implies\left|g(-a)\right| =\max\limits_{\left|x\right|=1}\left|g(x)\right|$$